# Threading problems when appending new web components

Tags: javascript, settimeout, web-component

I'm currently trying to build a webcomponent which appends another component as part of its template. But when trying to access the JS API of that child component I get a functionName is undefined error.

When appending my template to the DOM, I'm able to access the newly added Node with `querySelector`, but not its component API (i.e. publicAPI) Apparently the element is not yet fully initialized. Even if I bind an DOMNodeInserted to that element the API still remains undefined.

But as soon as I wrap it into a setTimeout with 0ms delay, which is a way to run the code in a different thread, it works.

Somehow this doesn't happen in Chrome and Firefox with enabled webcomponent feature, when loading the component script with HTML imports.

I would like to find the cause of this threading problem and avoid any setTimeout if possible.

This is my code, or as [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewyttauk/3/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.5.5-rc1/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div is="x-div"><b>test</b></div>

        <template id="x-div-tmpl">
            <section is="x-component" class="wrapper"></section>
        </template>

        <script>
            var XDiv = document.registerElement('x-div', {
                extends: 'div',
                prototype: Object.create(HTMLDivElement.prototype, {
                    createdCallback: {
                        value: function() {
                            var _this = this,
                                template = document.querySelector('#x-div-tmpl'),
                                wrapper = template.content.querySelector('.wrapper');

                            // move all child nodes inside the template wrapper container
                            while (this.firstChild) {
                                wrapper.appendChild(this.firstChild);
                            }
                            var tmpl = document.importNode(template.content, true);
                            this.wrapper = tmpl.querySelector('.wrapper');
                            this.wrapper.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e){
                                if(e.target === _this.wrapper) {
                                    console.log('DOMNodeInserted', _this.wrapper, ' ' + typeof _this.wrapper.publicAPI); // HTMLElement, undefined
                                }
                            });
                            this.appendChild(tmpl);

                            console.log(this.wrapper, typeof this.wrapper.publicAPI); // HTMLElement, undefined
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                console.log('setTimeout', _this.wrapper, typeof _this.wrapper.publicAPI); // HTMLElement, function
                            }, 0);
                        }
                    }
                })
            });


            var XComponent = document.registerElement('x-component', {
                extends: 'section',
                prototype: Object.create(HTMLDivElement.prototype, {
                    createdCallback: {
                        value: function() {
                            console.log('XComponent:createdCallback');
                        }
                    },
                    attachedCallback: {
                        value: function() {
                            console.log('XComponent::attachedCallback');
                        }
                    },
                    publicAPI: {
                        value: function() {
                            console.log('XComponent::publicAPI');
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner-component's `cratedCallback` or `attachedCallback` should issue an event:

```
attachedCallback: {
    value: function () {
        var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent("attached", true, true);
        event.eventName = "attached";
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
```

Then your outer-component listens to it:

```
this.wrapper.addEventListener('attached',
    function (e) {
        console.log(_this.wrapper, ' ' + typeof _this.wrapper.publicAPI); 
    });
```

**Your complete working code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.5.5-rc1/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div is="x-div"><b>test</b></div>

<template id="x-div-tmpl">
    <section is="x-component" class="wrapper"></section>
</template>

<script>
    var XDiv = document.registerElement('x-div', {
        extends: 'div',
        prototype: Object.create(HTMLDivElement.prototype, {
            createdCallback: {
                value: function ()
                    {
                    var _this = this,
                            template = document.querySelector('#x-div-tmpl'),
                            wrapper = template.content.querySelector('.wrapper');

                    // move all child nodes inside the template wrapper container
                    while (this.firstChild)
                        {
                        wrapper.appendChild(this.firstChild);
                        }
                    var tmpl = document.importNode(template.content, true);
                    this.wrapper = tmpl.querySelector('.wrapper');

                    this.wrapper.addEventListener('attached', function (e)
                    {
                    if (e.target === _this.wrapper)
                        {
                        console.log(_this.wrapper, ' ' + typeof _this.wrapper.publicAPI); // HTMLElement, function
                        }
                    });

                    this.appendChild(tmpl);
                    }
            }
        })
    });

    var XComponent = document.registerElement('x-component', {
        extends: 'section',
        prototype: Object.create(HTMLDivElement.prototype, {
            createdCallback: {
                value: function ()
                    {
                    console.log('XComponent:createdCallback');
                    }
            },
            attachedCallback: {
                value: function ()
                    {
                    console.log('XComponent::attachedCallback');

                    var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                    event.initEvent("attached", true, true);
                    event.eventName = "attached";
                    this.dispatchEvent(event);
                    }
            },
            publicAPI: {
                value: function ()
                    {
                    console.log('XComponent::publicAPI');
                    }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```